# Client certificate must be supplied

Tags: github-actions, tls1.2, client-certificates, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I am working on one of the TLS auth certificate based authentication with Hashicorp vault.
I am trying to authenticate same with github pipeline with runs on ubuntu-latest
Keeping public and private certificate in root of repo

Below is the code in yaml

On executing above the error is : {"errors": ["client certificate must be supplied]}

I have tried supplying --cacert argument as a curl-ca-bundle.crt, but this didn't work.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather pass the actual certificate as a secret in your GitHub Action, rather than relying on some `curl-ca-bundle.crt` already present on the runner machine.

```yaml
- name: Copy certificate from secret
  run: |
    echo "$CERT_SECRET" > /path/to/cert.pem
  env:
    CERT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_CERT_SECRET }}

- name: Make curl call with --cacert option
  run: |
    curl --cacert /path/to/cert.pem https://example.com/api
  env:
    CERT_PATH: /path/to/cert.pem
```

Or you can extract the certificate first:

```yaml
- name: Extract certificate from URL
  run: |
    openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > /path/to/cert.pem
  env:
    CERT_PATH: /path/to/cert.pem
```

---

If you need a key in addition to the certificate, then there is no extraction possible, and you need to set that key as a secret:

```yaml
- name: Make curl call with client certificate and key
  run: |
    if [ -z "$CERT_PATH" ]; then
      echo "Certificate path not provided"
      exit 1
    fi
    if [ -z "$KEY_SECRET" ]; then
      echo "Key secret not provided"
      exit 1
    fi
    echo "$KEY_SECRET" > /path/to/key.pem
    curl --cacert "$CERT_PATH" --key /path/to/key.pem https://example.com/api
  env:
    CERT_PATH: /path/to/cert.pem
    KEY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_KEY_SECRET }}
```

Comment: I have tried by making the change as --cacert cert.pem and keeping everything as it is. But getting same error.Is any other way other than storing it in secret?

Comment: One more thing when i run the same command in command prompt i am getting the token which expected to me, but same is not working with piepeline

Comment: @kkg If you extract the certificate from the HTTPS URL, you would not need a secret.

Comment: @kkg "token"? Why do you need a token? That seems unrelated to "client certificate".

Comment: Sorry, but my goal is to fetch secrets from hashicorp vault. For this I am authenticating first with public_cert and privatekey. So I believe once I will authenticate, I will receive token. So second step would be to get secrets based on token.

Comment: @kkg OK. Your question is about the first step, right? Does that first step work now? Can you extract the certificate needed to make any call to your HashiCorp Vault HTTPS URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252933/discussion-between-kkg-and-vonc).